# Save Email Response in Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email, cakephp

I have an application that works this way.
I have a users table in mysql with user id and all data

This is what happens:

a) A user signed up to my site(A) goes to another website(B) and answers some question.

b) The website(B) Sends me email with data of a user who is in my database.

now what i want to do is automatically whenever an eamil about a particular received in my inbox. The code in php detects the user id and saves the mail in emailrep field of my database.

Please tell me how can i achieve this in PHP???

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good start
[Reading Emails with PHP](http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/reading-emails-with-php/)